# How can I use a JMS adapter to listen Amazon SQS

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to setup an Amazon SQS Queue or Amazon SNS Topic in order to work as a native XA JMS Resource Adapter?

The idea is to replace the use of activemq in a large application with SQS, but avoid unnecessary code rewriting overhead.

Aborting automatically the currrent XA transaction, when the message visibility times out, would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nevado](http://nevado.skyscreamer.org/) is a JMS driver that supports SQS and SNS. It's very focused on JMS spec compliance, so it should be a good tool for porting off of ActiveMQ.

Comment: Unfortunately, XA compliance is about the only part of the JMS spec not covered by Nevado: https://github.com/skyscreamer/nevado/wiki/Master-Feature-Grid

It does support non-distributed transactions, so you might be able to write some helper code to make it fit your purpose.

Comment: I'll check it out, fortunately I'm using grails, which is spring based , and for my current purposes XA compliance is not an issue.